# Need to extract string for full path with file name through Unix Command

Tags: unix

i have below filename with full path

```
/operations/MIC/fin/4430/out/export/ord.20200917-000075.850

file name = ord.20200917-000075.850
```

i have to extract '20200917-000075' this string through unix command

i have tried below command and it's working. but i need it in single command.
could any one can help me out?

```
a='/operations/MIC/fin/4430/out/export/ord.20200917-000075.850'
b="${a##*/}"
c="${b%.*}"
d="${c##*.}"
echo $d
```

Comment: why worry about a single command. This is the most efficient method to do this. If  you call sed, the "expense" of creating a new process is much greater than the parameter substitutions. Else do the same operations inside of a sed script, i.e. `echo "$string" | sed 's@^.*/@@;s/\.[0-9][0-9]*$/;.... etc' ;-)`. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter tried but not working, am not good at unix. could please write down the command in comments

Comment: `echo "/operations/MIC/fin/4430/out/export/ord.20200917-000075.850" | sed 's@.*/@@;s/\.[0-9][0-9]*$//;s/^.*\.//'` output: `20200917-000075`. Good luck.